# ACPI and integrity error on ubuntu

Tags: kernel, bios, acpi

I'm having trouble installing Linux system on my laptop (Lenovo Legion 5i-15IMH05). I have managed to install Ubuntu 20.10 but I still get ACPI BIOS ERROR and integrity errors. I done everything about it but nothing worked: my BIOS is in the last version possible (EFCN46WW), I enrolled the key in MOK management to enable Secure Boot. Looked at all the options on the Bios and nothing worked. Can someone help.

[ACPI_LOG](https://gist.github.com/upwardweb/bab8ff1d3284bcf098421258875f4f63)

Erros IMG
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error occurs because the [ACPI](https://uefi.org/sites/default/files/resources/ACPI_6_3_final_Jan30.pdf) (Advanced Configuration and Power Interface) objects can't be found in the [AML](https://wiki.osdev.org/AML) DSDT or SSDT ACPI tables, this normally indicates a BIOS bug.  I believe the objects are related to the touch pad over the [I2C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I%C2%B2C) bus, but I may be wrong.

I've seen these errors before on similar firmware and think the objects relate to getting the status of the touchpad device via the _STA ACPI method.  I don't this this adversely affects the system, so personally speaking, I would not be overly concerned about this.

Comment: Thanks for the help. So, do you think there is a way to solve it or is best to ignore? And what about the integrity error. I realized that even if I disable secure boot I still get this error, but if a clear pk (enter setup mode ) the error is gone, and if I reset factory keys the error comes back. Any ideia?